# Joining pandas by column names for multiple files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, glob

I want to merge 2 dataframes on difference column names. It work on single file with

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv', header = 0)
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv', header = 0)

All = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', left_on = 'Name1', right_on = 'Name2')
All = All.drop('Name2', 1)
All.to_csv('all.csv', sep=',')
```

but for multiple files in glob (100 csv files in Descriptors/)

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv', header = 0)

for f in glob.glob('Descriptors/*.csv'):
     df2 = pd.read_csv(f)
     All = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', left_on = 'Name1', right_on = 'Name2')
     All = All.drop('Name2', 1)
     All.to_csv(f + 'all.csv', sep=',')
```

this can success only 1 loop and get the error

```
KeyError: 'Name2'
```

what wrong with my code?

Comment: Check the header row in all your .csv files.  Make sure the all named the same.

Comment: If they are in a consistent format you could use `names` argument to set the name of the column on the way in using `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: @ScottBoston yes, all header row contains 'Name2' in the first column.

Comment: @ScottBoston 'pd.read_csv' work for only 1 file, i need to do 100 file

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code is correct. but ERROR come from log.csv file which saves every time i try to run. So every new run glop will get this log.csv that cause an error.